# Powershell: Select statement to access a hash-table or collection property values by key

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, calculated-columns

I am trying to access specific "sub-properties" from a query in a select statement.

I have a group of user objects collected by the following command: `$azusers=Get-AzureADUser`

This list of objects, each contain several properties, some of which are collections/hash tables/etc. One of the properties I want to capture data from is the Extension Property.  This property looks like a hash table to me. For any given user object, I can access the Extension Property values by doing something like this:

```
$user=get-azureaduser|where{displayname="John Doe"}

$user.ExtensionProperty
```

the output from the above would be something like:

```
Key                         Value
---                         -----
odata.type                  Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
createdDateTime             1/13/2024 7:26:05 AM
employeeId                  
onPremisesDistinguishedName "cn=John Doe,cn=Users,dc=myonpremad,dc=com"
userIdentities              []
```

What I'm trying to do is include the createdDateTime and onPremisesDistinguishedName in an export to CSV. Below is my code:

```
$azusers = Get-AzureADUser -all $true
$azusers | Select-Object @{ n='createdTime'; e=$_.ExtensionProperty['createdDateTime']}, @{ n='onPremisesDistinguishedName'; e=$_.ExtensionProperty['onPremisesDistinguishedName']}, "DeletionTimestamp","ObjectId","ObjectType","AccountEnabled","AgeGroup","City","CompanyName","ConsentProvidedForMinor","Country","CreationType","Department","DirSyncEnabled", "DisplayName","FacsimileTelephoneNumber","GivenName","IsCompromised","ImmutableId","JobTitle","LastDirSyncTime","LegalAgeGroupClassification","Mail","MailNickName","Mobile", "OnPremisesSecurityIdentifier","PasswordPolicies","PasswordProfile","PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName","PostalCode","PreferredLanguage", @{n='proxyaddress1'; e=if($_.ProxyAddresses.count -gt 0){$_.ProxyAddresses[0]}else{$null}},@{n='proxyaddress2'; e=if($_.ProxyAddresses.count -gt 1){$_.ProxyAddresses[1]}else{$null}}, @{n='proxyaddress3'; e=if($_.ProxyAddresses.count -gt 2){$_.ProxyAddresses[2]}else{$null}},"RefreshTokensValidFromDateTime","ShowInAddressList","SipProxyAddress","State", "StreetAddress","Surname","TelephoneNumber","UsageLocation","UserPrincipalName","UserState","UserStateChangedOn","UserType"|export-csv -NoTypeInformation -path AZUsers.csv
```

I've tried this without the proxyAddresses calculated columns as well to ensure that wasn't introducing an error.

With the above command or the completely barebones version `$azusers|Select @{ n='createdTime'; e=$_.ExtensionProperty['createdDateTime']}` ; I get the following error:

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:1
+ $azusers|Select @{ n='createdTime'; e=$_.ExtensionProperty['createdDate ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

What am I missing?

I have tried various silly things like different syntax all with failing results (i.e. `$azusers|Select @{ n='createdTime'; e=$_.ExtensionProperty('createdDateTime')}` (round brackets)

or `$azusers|Select @{ n='createdTime'; e=$_.ExtensionProperty[createdDateTime]}` (no quotes)

or `$azusers|Select @{ n='createdTime'; e=$_.ExtensionProperty.createdDateTime}`

I assume I am overlooking something simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The end goal is to have all of the fields specified above in the longer select statement, exported by user into a CSV.

It is noteworthy that if I remove all of the calculated columns than the command works as expected.

Comment: You're missing the scriptblock in your `e` (expression): `e = { $_.ExtensionProperty['createdDateTime'] }` should work correctly. The linked answer has more details on this, it focuses on `.AdditionalProperties` property however the logic applies the same.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something simple like that.

Comment: It works now with the opening scriptblock bracket in place.

Comment: Also be aware that in some cases these dictionaries may be case-sensitive, meaning that `$_.ExtensionProperty['createdDateTime']` may work and `$_.ExtensionProperty['CreatedDateTime']` may not work